# Ignore case with multiple strings using str_detect in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I'm trying to use an "or" statement using `ignore_case` with `str_detect`. I want to convert everything that contains "ag" to "Agricultural" and everything that contains "field" to "Agricultural"

Here's an example:

```
(dat <- 
  data.frame(Class = c("ag", "Agricultural--misc", "old field")))
```

This works:

```
(dat %>% 
  mutate(Class_2 = case_when(
    # Aggregate all Agricultural classes
    str_detect(Class, fixed("Ag", ignore_case=TRUE)) ~ "Agricultural",
    # Convert 'field' to Agricultural
    str_detect(Class, fixed("field", ignore_case=TRUE)) ~ "Agricultural",
    TRUE ~ Class)))
```

But I want to condense the two lines to just one line, as below:

```
(dat %>% 
    mutate(Class_2 = case_when(
      # Aggregate all Agricultural and field classes to Agricultural
      str_detect(Class, fixed("Ag|field", ignore_case=TRUE)) ~ "Agricultural",
      TRUE ~ Class)))
```

Comment: You're using `fixed(.)`, so you cannot use the `|` regex (not-fixed) pattern component

Comment: Can I ignore case w/o using fixed?

Comment: Just found this (?i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be to bring everything to lower case and match that with `ag|field`.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(Class_2 = case_when(
    str_detect(string = str_to_lower(Class),
               pattern = "ag|field") ~ "Agricultural",
    TRUE ~ Class
  ))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Class              Class_2     
  <chr>              <chr>       
1 ag                 Agricultural
2 Agricultural--misc Agricultural
3 old field          Agricultural
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the `(?i)` argument.
So another solution would be to remove the `fixed()` argument, and add `(?i)` to the string like this:

```
(dat %>%
    mutate(Class_2 = case_when(
      # Aggregate all Agricultural and field classes to Agricultural
      str_detect(Class, "(?i)Ag|field") ~ "Agricultural",
      TRUE ~ Class)))
```

But I like the `str_to_lower` option, as the code is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `regex` like this:

```r
dat <- data.frame(Class = c("ag", "Agricultural--misc", "old field"))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(Class_2 = case_when(str_detect(Class, regex('Ag|field', ignore_case = T))~'Agricultural',
                             TRUE ~ Class))
#>                Class      Class_2
#> 1                 ag Agricultural
#> 2 Agricultural--misc Agricultural
#> 3          old field Agricultural
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>